# Как правильно прописать 301 динамический редирект на Apache?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, apache

site.ru/?page=3 на site.ru/page/3/ (цифра может быть любая)

Как правильно прописать 301 динамический редирект на Apache?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/регулярные-выражения/info

Answer (score 0):

наверное, так

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^$ /page/%1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Если остальные query параметры не нужны или их нет, можно QSA убрать

Comment: А как получить полный URL?

Если структура URL site.ru/cat/?page=1 то редиректит на site.ru/page/1/, а нужно site.ru/cat/page/1/